# Do not let user update a column value in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I m trying to basically not let anyone UPDATE a row value in MYSQL DB. I tried a simple logic using triggers. I created a trigger AFTER UPDATE in that particular table and passed an update query as an output. (Basically when someone updates that value trigger updates it back to the old one)

But looks like a failed attempt. After adding this trigger, when I try to update the value it flashes an error saying

> #1442 - Can't update table 'wp_options' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function/trigger

And sadly the value is updated and the trigger does not work.

How to prevent updation of that particular row?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I m trying to basically not let anyone UPDATE a row value in MYSQL db.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bu_prevent_data_change
BEFORE UPDATE
ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
    SET NEW.column1 = OLD.column1;
    -- another columns which must be non-changed
    SET NEW.columnN = OLD.columnN;
END
```

Apply when only some columns must be unchanged.

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bu_prevent_data_change
BEFORE UPDATE
ON table_name
FOR EACH ROW
SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000'
       SET MESSAGE_TEXT = 'The data in \'table_name\' cannot be altered!', 
           MYSQL_ERRNO = 1105;
```

Apply when any data change attempt is errorneous.

Comment: it worked like a charm ! just to fine tune it, is it possible that i can limit this to one row ? PFA the screenshot i just want to block users/programs from updating the Highlighted ROW in yellow color. Thanks !

Screenshot : https://ibb.co/LPHNhWB

Comment: @SagarMistry *is it possible that i can limit this to one row ?* Add according IF statement which checks does the affected row is one to be stayed unchanged, and revert changes / generate error only if the check is successful. Pay attention, that if the query updates a lot of rows where one of them must stay unchanged then use the former method - it will  revert only row in interest update whereas the latter method fails the whole query and none rows will be updated.